# Backup iCloud files to an external hard drive?

Tags: macos, hard-drive, backup, external-hard-drive, icloud

What are my options for backing up every file on my iCloud to an (exFAT) external hard disk?

Right now I have more files on iCloud than space on my Mac internal hard drive.

Copying folders from the iCloud drive on my Mac to the external hard disk isn't working - it starts downloading files to the internal drive which is not going to complete.

I have regular time machine backups - but this does not backup everything on iCloud, only the downloaded files.

All ideas are welcome! Thanks.

Comment: All other considerations aside, do not use ExFAT for Mac files. It will lose all unix permissions, ACLs & even break some structures entirely, like Logic projects and Photos libraries.

Comment: Ta for the tip... but in this instance I'm most interested in making sure the files are safe, usable under both windows and linux, and getting everything backed up ASAP.

Comment: The trouble then is that you're using iCloud as 'overflow' storage. Something has to give somewhere. You're probably going to end up copying files from your local folders, deleting, allowing more data to flow to you, rinse, repeat. tbh long-term, it's far better for your sanity if you use iCloud as purely a sync mechanism, not a storage mechanism. It was never designed to be storage [or backup for that matter]. Apple first scr*wed this pooch when they started selling laptops with abysmally small 128GB drives. There's no way out of it until everybody has at least a TB locally.

Comment: [You might have noticed I'm no fan of this structure, & personally refuse to use it for anything other than simple sync, keychain, Notes, calendar etc.] My smallest Mac has 1TB internal storage… largest 16TB. I like to be in charge of my own destiny, though I do have everything backed up at least twice, once at home, once online [Backblaze] ;))

Comment: "The trouble then is that you're using iCloud as 'overflow' storage." -- that hits the problem on the head. What I'd like is a way out of it that's not the mechanical task you describe!

Comment: I honestly don't know of any kind of 'get out of jail free' card for the situation you're in. You will have to pull the data back to your home computer to be able to transfer it anywhere 'safe'. You can't do that if your drive is too small, other than by throwing bits away as soon as they're safely stored elsewhere. I'm afraid you were 'sold a dream', as were a million others.

Comment: Thanks again for your help with this. I've spent a good amount of tie with Apple Support, who couldn't offer any other solution. I have the important data backed up manually as you describe, but it's frustrating that there isn't a proper solution.

Comment: Yeah - sometimes I hate being right, as it does no-one any good:\ It's a situation that never should have been allowed to happen, but at the time this all began, SSDs cost a fortune, so everybody bought lappies with teeny ones. Apple thought 'Hey, I know what we can do. Sell everybody the space online they don't have at home'… and on it went from there. You can now get 1TB SSD for about $£€100, but not in a new Mac at that price.